# jquery проблема с добавлением tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Такой вопрос, у меня есть tag с определенным id и я хочу после него, именно после него добавить любой tag, у меня не выходит, я добавляю только в данный tag детей(children)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод `after`.

```
$('#some_id').after('<div></div>');
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать.